# Checking if getElementsByTagName is contained in XML file

Tags: php, xml

Sometimes `FinalValueFee` is not included in the XML DOMDocument i'm trying to parse.
If this is not the case, I'd like to make `$finalvaluefee` = `NULL`.

I've tried `!empty` as such:

```
    $getfinalvaluefee = $doc->getElementsByTagName("FinalValueFee");

    if (!empty($getfinalvaluefee)) {
    $finalvaluefee2 = $getfinalvaluefee->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $finalvaluefee = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $finalvaluefee2);
    }

    else {
        $finalvaluefee2 = NULL;
        $finalvaluefee = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $finalvaluefee2);
    }
```

but I'm getting this error:

> > Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

for line `$finalvaluefee2 = $getfinalvaluefee->item(0)->nodeValue;`.

I've also tried `isset`, as such:

```
if (isset($getfinalvaluefee)) {
    $finalvaluefee2 = $getfinalvaluefee->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $finalvaluefee = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $finalvaluefee2);
}
```

Still, the same error for the same line.

> > Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

So it appears `!empty` and `isset` is not working, and, in these cases, the script always directs to the `if` statement instead of the `else` no matter what.

How can I check if a node exists as I'm attempting to do, and if not, revert to the `else` statement as I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if($getfinalvaluefee->length == 0)
{
  message('no nodes')
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That works.  In my case above it'd `if ($getfinalvaluefee->length != 0) {` instead of the `!empty` or `isset` and it seems to go to the else without issue.